# How to scrape data from nasdaq omx nordic

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-scraping, .net-core

I have tried to scrape the price directly from here http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/etp/etn/etninfo?Instrument=SSE132883
using the using Html Agility Pack Plugin.

That didnt work so i looked into what requests are being made when i access the page. There are some calls to the following url with some form data. http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx.

I tried to replicate this by creating a request using postman and passing the same form data through but am getting an invalid request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already noticed, all you need is to post the correct input to "http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx".

I copied the requestXML below from chrome's developer window.

```
string url = "http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx";
string requestXML = @"<post>
                    <param name=""Exchange"" value=""NMF""/>
                    <param name=""SubSystem"" value=""Prices""/>
                    <param name=""Action"" value=""GetInstrument""/>
                    <param name=""inst__a"" value=""""/>
                    <param name=""ext_xslt"" value=""/nordicV3/trades_table.xsl""/>
                    <param name=""inst.an"" value=""nm""/>
                    <param name=""inst__e"" value=""3""/>
                    <param name=""Instrument"" value=""SSE132883""/>
                    <param name=""ext_xslt_lang"" value=""en""/>
                    <param name=""ext_xslt_hiddenattrs"" value="",x,id,tr,""/>
                    <param name=""ext_xslt_tableId"" value=""tradesForShareTable""/>
                    <param name=""ext_xslt_options"" value="",noflag,menu,""/>
                    <param name=""app"" value=""/etp/etn/etninfo""/>
                    </post>";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "xmlquery", requestXML }
    };
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var resp = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    var html = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var table = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr")
                    .Select(tr =>
                    new
                    {
                        Id = tr.Attributes["id"]?.Value,
                        Data = tr.Elements("td").Select(x => x.InnerText).ToList()
                    })
                    .Where(x => x.Id != null)
                    .ToList();

}
```

Comment: The url and request data is exactly what i tried with postman with the request headers too but got invalid URL. i never thought it would just work the HTTP client but it does. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the Html Agility Data Pack, used it in past, but currently the most stuff I'd scrape is using JavaScript (or JQuery). Especially if it loads the stuff with ajax or needs ability to render JS, then you need browser component or 
 headless browser. Getting it like this also means that if the website updates prices in real time (i.e. no need to reload) then you as well dont need to start new session every time, just reread the dom again after 5 seconds of sleep, really efficent for some scraping tasks.

Checkout PhantomJS or Selenium with Chrome driver (PhantomJS driver is not updated since some time).